# Merging certain elements in a c++ vector or similar data structure in the most efficient way

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, c++11

How do I merge certain elements in a vector or similar data structure by only iterating over the complete list once? Is there a more efficient way than what I have got?

I have a vector of vectors of points: `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours`

And I need to compare always two of them and then decide if I want to merge them or continue comparing.

ContourMoments has some helper functions to calculate the distance between points for example. The function `merge()` only takes all the points from one ContourMoments object and adds them to the calling ContourMoments object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


class ContourMoments
{
private:
    void init()
    {
        moments = cv::moments(contour);
        center = cv::Point2f(moments.m10 / moments.m00, moments.m01 / moments.m00);
        float totalX = 0.0, totalY = 0.0;
        for (auto const&p : contour)
        {
            totalX += p.x;
            totalY += p.y;
        }
        gravitationalCenter = cv::Point2f(totalX / contour.size(), totalY / contour.size());
    }
public:
    cv::Moments moments;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> contour;
    cv::Point2f center;
    cv::Point2f gravitationalCenter;
    
    ContourMoments(const std::vector<cv::Point2f> &c)
    {
        contour = c;
        init();
    }
    
    ContourMoments(const ContourMoments &cm)
    {
        contour = cm.contour;
        init();
    }
    
    void merge(const ContourMoments &cm)
    {
        contour.insert(contour.end(), std::make_move_iterator(cm.contour.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(cm.contour.end()));
        init();
    }
    
    float horizontalDistanceTo(const ContourMoments &cm)
    {
        return std::abs(center.x - cm.center.x);
    }

    float verticalDistanceTo(const ContourMoments &cm)
    {
        return std::abs(center.y - cm.center.y);
    }

    float centerDistanceTo(const ContourMoments &cm)
    {
        return std::sqrt(std::pow(center.x - cm.center.x, 2) + std::pow(center.y - cm.center.y, 2));
    }
    
    ContourMoments() = default;
    ~ContourMoments() = default;
};

float RandomFloat(float a, float b) {
    float random = ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX;
    float diff = b - a;
    float r = random * diff;
    return a + r;
}

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> createData()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> cs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> c;
        int j_stop = rand()%11;
        for (int j = 0; j < j_stop; ++j) {
            c.push_back(cv::Point2f(RandomFloat(0.0, 20.0), RandomFloat(0.0, 20.0)));
        }
        cs.push_back(c);
    }
    return cs;
}

void printVectorOfVectorsOfPoints(const std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> &cs) {
    std::cout << "####################################################" << std::endl;
    for (const auto &el : cs) {
        bool first = true;
        for (const auto &pt : el) {
            if (!first) {
                std::cout << ", ";
            }
            first = false;
            std::cout << "{x: " + std::to_string(pt.x) + ", y: " + std::to_string(pt.y) + "}";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "####################################################" << std::endl;
}

void merge(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> &contours, int &counterMerged){
    for(auto it = contours.begin() ; it < contours.end() ; /*++it*/)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        if (it->size() < 5)
        {
            it = contours.erase(it);
            continue;
        }
        for (auto it2 = it + 1; it2 < contours.end(); /*++it2*/)
        {
            if (it2->size() < 5)
            {
                it2 = contours.erase(it2);
                continue;
            }
            ContourMoments cm1(*it);
            ContourMoments cm2(*it2);
            if (cm1.centerDistanceTo(cm2) > 4.0)
            {
                ++counter;
                ++it2;
                continue;
            }
            counterMerged++;
            cm1.merge(std::move(cm2));
            it2 = contours.erase(it2);
        }
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            std::advance(it, counter);
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> contours = createData();
    printVectorOfVectorsOfPoints(contours);
    int counterMerged = 0;
    merge(contours, counterMerged);
    printVectorOfVectorsOfPoints(contours);
    std::cout << "Merged " << std::to_string(counterMerged) << " vectors." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Best wishes

## Edit

posted the complete example - install opencv first

This generates 2000 vectors of up to 10 points and merges them if they are close together.

Comment: could you sort the container first based on center distance?

Comment: I could, but that means a lot of iterations over the vector which I would really like to avoid because of performance reasons.

Comment: You could use a lambda function for sorting as @user6386155 suggests to make it faster.

Comment: But doesn't that only hide the iterations?

Comment: How does `centerDistanceTo` look like? What computations does it perform?

Comment: the center is calculated with the moments of the contour: 
`moments = cv::moments(contour);
center = cv::Point2f(moments.m10 / moments.m00, moments.m01 / moments.m00);` and the centerDistanceTo function uses this: 
`float centerDistanceTo(const ContourMoments &cm)
{
  return std::sqrt(std::pow(center.x - cm.center.x, 2) + std::pow(center.y - cm.center.y, 2));
}`

Comment: I'm not sure you can make it linear, as you seem to want to evaluate all the pairs of contours. However, `erase` seems to be a pessimization -- i'd consider keeping an array of (boolean) flags to mark the undesired ones. You also calculate `ContourMoments` more than once per contour -- avoid that and cache them. | Please, provide a proper [mcve], including a sample input we can run this on.

Comment: Caching them seems like a good idea! - what do you mean with erase being a pessimization? I don't look for pairs but rather for all contours in the same region.

Comment: Give me a minute to create that example... :)

Comment: Well, you iterate through `contours` from the beginning, and erase all the small ones, and all the ones you merged. Every `erase` means that all the subsequent elements in the vector have to be moved one position forward. | Take your time, I've gotta head out for a moment, and I'll check back here later.

Comment: @i7clock Just a thought about efficiency... Why don't you compare squared distances instead of distances? sqrt(x) is a costly operation, and by the looks of your code, the distance isn't used anywhere except for tolerance comparison.
Also, if you want to erase stuff in the vector, it will be more efficient if you iterate over it starting at the end, as erase will shift elements, and some of them could be merged in the first place.

Comment: How do you obtain the contours? If you use findContours then you could use the option CV_RETR_TREE and compare only contours close to each other in the created tree.

Comment: This merge operation seems to depend on the order of contours in your array. Is this correct? As soon as you merge two contours, the center of the first one might move further away from the center of a third one. Before the merge, contour 1 and contour 3 could have been merged. But not after the merge of 1 and 2. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: @AlexG good point with squared distances! I will try iterate through the vector from the back ... need some time to redo the sample code. Today I probably don't have time for it but thanks for the idea!

Comment: @Cristi indeed I use findContours and I use CV_RETR_CCOMP for performance reasons. Outer and inner contours are written to the same level. I don't use hierarchy at the moment.

Comment: @Nico Schertler that is true but in my case doesn't really have an impact because the set of contours I am searching for are either close together or far away, but might have some very close neighbors that shall be merged.

Answer (score 2):

For each of your contours, you can pre-compute the centers. Then, what you want to do is to cluster the contours. Each pair of contours whose center is at most a distance of `d` apart should belong to the same cluster.

This can be done with a simple radius query. Like this:

```
for each contour ci in all contours
    for each contour cj with cluster center at most d away from ci
        merge cluster ci and cj
```

For the radius query, I would suggest something like a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Enter all your contours into the tree and then you can query for the neighbors in `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)` like you are doing now.

For the merging part, I would suggest a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). This lets you do the merge in practically constant time. At the end, you can just gather all your contour data into a big cluster contour.

Comment: Clustering seems like a good idea thanks for the input I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't scrutinize your code. If what you want to do is to scan the vector, form groups of contiguous points and emit a single point per group, in sequence, e.g.

```
a b c|d e|f g h|i j k|l => a b c d f i l
```

the simplest is to perform the operation in-place.

Keep an index after the last emitted point, let `n` (initially `0`), and whenever you emit an new one, store it at `array[n++]`, overwriting this element, which has already been processed. In the end, resize the array.

One might think of a micro-optimization to compare `n` to the current index, and avoid overwriting an element with itself. Anyway, as soon as an element has been dropped, the test becomes counter-productive.

Comment: To create a new array is a good idea and keeping track of the current set is also a good idea I try to implement this and check if it is a better solution for my problem thanks!

Comment: @i7clock: I exactly suggested *not* to create a new array. My explanation must have been quite unclear.

Comment: Sry i misunderstood then. Please elaborate

Comment: @i7clock: I said in-place, didn't I ?